# Bash Array ; Sed AWK

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am searching for the line just before any matches of the regex and
put the output into an array variable so we can iterate over
another array with the regex match lines. This way we know 
what the context is when it's time to print it out at the 
end of each line.

```
    <context name="Security" category="security" type="generic" optimizeSize="1">

    <field name="BID_ASK_LASK_PRICE" type="double" id="0xFBCB" sequence="1" defaultValue="!null"/>
    <field name="PX_OPEN_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT" type="double" id="0x79F5" sequence="1" defaultValue="!null"/>
    <field name="PX_CLOSE_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT" type="double" id="0x79F6" sequence="1" defaultValue="!null"/>
    <field name="PX_HIGH_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT" type="double" id="0x79F7" sequence="1"
```

Desired out put would appear Field Name|id|Context. In example

```
CURRENT_SESSION_RT|0xFBCB|Security
PX_OPEN_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT|0x79F5|Security
```

Current logic is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

array=($(sed -n '/field name/{g;1!p;};h' $1))
array2=($(sed -n '/field name/p' $1))
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};++i)); do
    ref=$(printf "${array2[1]}|" | sed 's/\"//g' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
    name=$(printf "${array2[2]}|" | sed 's/[\"\>]//g' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
    id=$(printf "${array[i]}\n" | sed 's/\"//g' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
    printf "${ref}${name}${id}\n"
done
```

Looks like it is not iterating and appending properly as output is just repeating the following

```
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"Security"
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"security"
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"generic"
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"1">
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"Security"
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"security"
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"generic"
BID_ASK_LAST_PRICE|double|"1">
```

Comment: How is the desired output obtained? specification about the relationship among the fields would be useful

Comment: I used to run the below one liner to get the field name and id seperated by a "|". I am now looking to add the 'context name'                                        grep 'field name=".*id="' file.name| sed -e 's/.*field name="//' -e  's/".*id="/|/' -e 's/".*//' | grep -v "[-]1$"

Comment: @shelter I am not sure what you are suggesting? I am simply asking for assistance. No different than most people who are 'stuck' or not experts.  Your advice is to look else where is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Super_Py_Me you want to print the name and id of the first two field names, followed by the context name? is that you want? also i dont see any `CURRENT_SESSION_RT` line in input file

Comment: @nu11p01n73R   is that you want? That is the end game and I seem to be stuck.

Comment: @Super_Py_Me chill man there is no end game. please clarify my doubt if you want `BID_ASK_LASK_PRICE` in output then i can help but if `CURRENT_SESSION_RT` i didnt understand from where you got that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` and `sed`

```
$ name=`grep -oP '(?<=context name=")([^"]+)' input`
$ sed -r "/context/d; s/^.*name=\"([^ ]+)\".*id=\"([^ ]+)\".*$/\1|\2|$name/g" input
```

will give output as

```
BID_ASK_LASK_PRICE|0xFBCB|Security
PX_OPEN_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT|0x79F5|Security
PX_CLOSE_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT|0x79F6|Security
PX_HIGH_ALL_WITH_SWITCHOVER_RT|0x79F7|Security
```

OR if `grep` doesnt support `-P`

```
$ name=`sed -r 's/^<context name="([^ ]+)".*$/\1/g;q' input`
$ sed -r "/context/d; s/^.*name=\"([^ ]+)\".*id=\"([^ ]+)\".*$/\1|\2|$name/g" input
```

Comment: this appears to stop at the 2nd field for me and does not continiue to iterate.  I believe the count < 2

Comment: I receive the following gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: match() cannot have 3 arguments

Comment: $ awk -F[=\ ] 'BEGIN{OFS="|" } /context name/{cn=$3}  /field/{match($0,"id=[^ ]+",id); match($0, "name=[^ ]+",name);sub("name=", "", name[0]); sub("id=", "", id[0]); print cn, name[0], id[0]}' file.log
gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: match() cannot have 3 arguments

Comment: does this need to be scripted or can i run from the command prompt? sorry I am a bit new on this

Comment: sorry that this is to much trouble. still an issue gawk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{OFS="|" }/context/{cn=$3}/field/{match($0,"id=[^ ]+"); idstart = RSTART+3; idlen=RLENGTH-3;match($0,"name=[^ ]+"); namestart=RSTART+5; namelen=RLENGTH-5;print substr($0,namestart, namelen), substr($0,idstart, idlen),cn}}
gawk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                 ^ parse error